# Mockito: inject a class mock into a private interface field

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using Mockito 1.9.5 to do some unit testing. I'm trying to inject a concrete class mock into a class that has a private interface field. Here's an example:

**Class I'm testing**

```
@Component
public class Service {

    @Autowired 
    private iHelper helper;

    public void doSomething() {
        helper.helpMeOut();
    }
}
```

**My test for this class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private iHelper helper;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        service = new Service();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStuff() {
        doNothing().when(helper).helpMeOut();
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This code throws a NullPointerException when trying to call helper.helpMeOut() in doSomething(). I debugged and found that helper was null when running the test. I also tried changing iHelper to the concrete class Helper, and the same issue happened.

Any suggestions? How can I get Mockito to correctly inject a mock into an interface private field?

Comment: What you're doing is exactly correct.  This is supposed to work.  In fact, it works for me; I often use exactly this approach. You could try posting this to the Mockito users list if you want the real Mockito experts to see it.

Comment: Why don't you change `helper`field visibility to default? I guess the Service is in the same package as its test.

Comment: @ponomandr That won't help.  The `@InjectMocks` code has some reflection magic that allows it to set private fields.

Comment: How about `service`? Is it instantiated at all? Although unlikely, maybe your IDE/console is not picking up mockito's runner.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my @Before method where I instantiate service. I've edited the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@acdcjunior's comment helped me figure out the issue. Instantiating service using the new keyword caused Spring to not inject the dependencies (in this case helper) correctly. I fixed this by autowiring in service in the test. My final working code looks like this:

**Class I'm testing**

```
@Component
public class Service {

    @Autowired 
    private iHelper helper;

    public void doSomething() {
        helper.helpMeOut();
    }
}
```

**My test for this class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private iHelper helper;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void testStuff() {
        doNothing().when(helper).helpMeOut();
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: what to do if I do not have a spring application. I have a simple java SE application. How can I get @Autowired

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) you are missing the setup.

```
@Before
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Edited*

Take at look at this page [why you should not use @InjectMock to autowire fields](http://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/)

Comment: Actually, this is not necessary if I'm using the @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) annotation: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html

Comment: As @zongweil says, if you use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` , then `initMocks` is called for you.  So this answer is incorrect.

Comment: You were right, sorry for that. Then i found that. Hope it works!

Comment: This is actually the right answer if you use TestNG